# How to simplify string concatenation in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I have this function:

```
myF :: String -> String
myF arg1 = "const" ++ arg1
```

Is there any way to simplify it? I think it might have to do with the operator "." but I can't figure out how to apply it here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The magic of currying:

```
myF :: String -> String
myF = (++) "const"
```

or (as mentioned by @jamshidh)

```
myF :: String -> String
myF = ("const" ++)
```

**Explanation**

We say (++) is a function takes two arguments but really all functions in Haskell take only one argument. Lets look at the signature for the (++) function:

```
(++) :: String -> String -> String
```

We can describe (++) or "the concatenation" function as acting like so:

> "Take one string and return a function that takes another string
>   concatenates (joins together) the two strings and return that string"

So when we say `myF = (++) "const"` we are assigning the resulting function from applying the first string to (++) function to `myF` function. This is known as **"Partial Application"**.

Notice we don't need to include an argument at the end of function like this but this is still perfectly fine:

```
myF arg = "const" ++ arg
```

We can leave out the "arg" because from the partially applied "concat" function we already know that we are expecting one more string argument.

Comment: And of course, you can always use directly on code as ("const" ++)

Comment: @jamshidh of course! added it to the answer, thanks mate